# Is it bad that I closed Disk Management console while creating a VHD?

Tags: windows-7

I was in the process of creating a VHD in order to install Windows 8 on Win7 x64 Ent when I closed the Computer Management console. I can no longer connect to the Disk Management service  and cannot delete the .vhd file because it is open in "System." Did I mess up all chances of this being a viable disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Unlocker.exe or Sysinternals' Handle.exe to unlock that file, and delete after it.

Comment: @swasheck , if this doesn't help you, I can tell you a way to enter as user "System". But then you must be careful, because you can change/delete/... everything.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I used Unlocker to handle it. Thank you.